# How to display an Image in Java using a simple program to terminal screen?

Tags: java

I'm new to programming (and new to Java).
I want to write a program that reads an image file from disk and Displays it on output screen of compiler. I don't want to use swing, jframe, jpanel because I am compiling my program on an IDE app for Android. I  googling it from 3 days and can't do it. Plz help me.
Im trying following code. It compiles successfully without any error and terminal says [program finished]. But no image is displayed.

```
import java.io.File; 

import java.io.IOException; 

import 
java.awt.image.BufferedImage; 

import javax.imageio.ImageIO; 

import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;



public class Display
{ 
public static void main(String 
args[])throws IOException
{ 
try{ 
    BufferedImage image = 
ImageIO.read(new 
File("picture2.jpg"));
        
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
       
g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
}    
        
   catch(IOException e) { 
   System.out.println("Error: "+e); 
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: You need to add your code to your question.

Comment: This ain't possible. You cannot display an image in a command line interface.

Comment: Thanx. I didn't knew that. But then what exactly the code I've written  doing?

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you for your suggestion. I've added code. Could you please help me?

Comment: You are creating an image in memory, but to display it you need to get it to something which knows how to render it to the screen. You could write it to a file and open that with some image viewing program, for instance.